# How can I render an image in a theme?

Tags: media, 7, theming

I need to display an image in the page footer using the `<img>` tag. In the *page.tpl.php* template file, I added this code.

```php
<div id="copyright">
  <img src="../images/logo.png">
   <p class="copyright"><?php print t('Copyright'); ?> &copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?></p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I am not rendering the theme logo, so I cannot use `print $logo`.

Comment: What has your own research led you to try so far? What of that research didn't work? Drupal Answers is specifically not a site where you can come and ask people to write your code for you, please make sure you include your own efforts in the question so we know that's not what you're here for :)

Answer (score 0):

add image in this way,

```
<img src="/sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/logo.png" />
```